# cpan install fails with "'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command"

Tags: perl, cpan

I am using Strawberry Perl 64-bit on Windows (5.26.2.1). Some CPAN modules install correctly, such as Log::Log4perl. However a lot of different modules are failing install with the same error: `'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command`.

I'm not really sure what to do about this. My best guess is that maybe these modules don't work with Windows, but that's just a guess. An example is Text::Trim which doesn't have any message in its docs that it wouldn't work on Windows.

If you know how to make CPAN install messages more verbose, that might also help track this down. Here is the error:

```
cpan[6]> install Text::Trim
install Text::Trim
Running install for module 'Text::Trim'
Checksum for C:\Users\me\.cpan\sources\authors\id\M\MA\MATTLAW\Text-Trim-1.02.tar.gz ok
Configuring M/MA/MATTLAW/Text-Trim-1.02.tar.gz with Build.PL
Created MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
Creating new 'Build' script for 'Text-Trim' version '1.02'
  MATTLAW/Text-Trim-1.02.tar.gz
  C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe Build.PL installdirs=site -- OK
Running Build for M/MA/MATTLAW/Text-Trim-1.02.tar.gz
Building Text-Trim
  MATTLAW/Text-Trim-1.02.tar.gz
  C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe ./Build -- OK
Running Build test
t\01..trim.t ..... ok
t\02..ltrim.t .... ok
t\03..rtrim.t .... ok
t\04..unicode.t .. ok
t\05..undef.t .... ok
t\99..pod.t ...... ok
All tests successful.
Files=6, Tests=63,  2 wallclock secs ( 0.05 usr +  0.70 sys =  0.75 CPU)
Result: PASS
  MATTLAW/Text-Trim-1.02.tar.gz
  C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe ./Build test -- OK
Running Build install
'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
  MATTLAW/Text-Trim-1.02.tar.gz
  ./Build install  -- NOT OK
Failed during this command:
 MATTLAW/Text-Trim-1.02.tar.gz                : install NO
```

Note that I also have Berrybrew installed, so I was also thinking they could interfere with each other, but the fact that Log::Log4perl works makes me think it's relatively unlikely.

EDIT: Strangely, installing Text::Trim using **cpanm** worked...

EDIT: Per request in the comments, here is the output from `o conf` from the cpan command prompt below. Note however that the cpan this is running is at `C:\berrybrew\5.26.1_64\perl\bin\cpan.bat` so it's strange that it's picking up other versions of certain things from `C:\Strawberry\c\bin`.

```
cpan[2]> o conf
$CPAN::Config options from C:\Users\me\.cpan/CPAN/MyConfig.pm:
    commit             [Commit changes to disk]
    defaults           [Reload defaults from disk]
    help               [Short help about 'o conf' usage]
    init               [Interactive setting of all options]

    applypatch         []
    auto_commit        [0]
    build_cache        [100]
    build_dir          [C:\Users\me\.cpan\build]
    build_dir_reuse    [0]
    build_requires_install_policy [yes]
    bzip2              [/mingw64/bin/bzip2]
    cache_metadata     [1]
    check_sigs         [0]
    cleanup_after_install undef
    colorize_debug     undef
    colorize_output    [0]
    colorize_print     undef
    colorize_warn      undef
    commandnumber_in_prompt [1]
    commands_quote     undef
    connect_to_internet_ok [1]
    cpan_home          [C:\Users\me\.cpan]
    curl               [C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\Library\bin\curl.EXE]
    dontload_hash      undef
    dontload_list      undef
    ftp                undef
    ftp_passive        [1]
    ftp_proxy          []
    ftpstats_period    undef
    ftpstats_size      undef
    getcwd             [cwd]
    gpg                [/usr/bin/gpg]
    gzip               [/usr/bin/gzip]
    halt_on_failure    [0]
    histfile           [C:\Users\me\.cpan\histfile]
    histsize           [100]
    http_proxy         []
    inactivity_timeout [0]
    index_expire       [1]
    inhibit_startup_message [0]
    keep_source_where  [C:\Users\me\.cpan\sources]
    load_module_verbosity [none]
    lynx               undef
    make               [C:\Strawberry\c\bin\gmake.EXE]
    make_arg           []
    make_install_arg   []
    make_install_make_command [C:\Strawberry\c\bin\gmake.EXE]
    makepl_arg         [INSTALLDIRS=site]
    mbuild_arg         []
    mbuild_install_arg []
    mbuild_install_build_command [./Build]
    mbuildpl_arg       [installdirs=site]
    ncftp              undef
    ncftpget           undef
    no_proxy           []
    pager              [C:\windows\system32\more.COM]
    password           undef
    patch              [C:\Strawberry\c\bin\patch.EXE]
    patches_dir        undef
    perl5lib_verbosity [none]
    plugin_list
    prefer_external_tar [0]
    prefer_installer   [MB]
    prefs_dir          [C:\Users\me\.cpan\prefs]
    prerequisites_policy [follow]
    proxy_pass         undef
    proxy_user         undef
    randomize_urllist  undef
    recommends_policy  [1]
    scan_cache         [atstart]
    shell              [C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe]
    show_unparsable_versions [0]
    show_upload_date   [0]
    show_zero_versions [0]
    suggests_policy    [0]
    tar                [/usr/bin/tar]
    tar_verbosity      [none]
    term_is_latin      [1]
    term_ornaments     [1]
    test_report        [0]
    trust_test_report_history [0]
    unzip              [/usr/bin/unzip]
    urllist
        0 [http://www.cpan.org/]
    use_prompt_default [0]
    use_sqlite         [0]
    username           undef
    version_timeout    [15]
    wait_list          undef
    wget               []
    yaml_load_code     [0]
    yaml_module        [YAML]
```

Comment: If system commands are being used by the installer (at all), you may have better luck installing from MINGW.  `SourceTree` (a UI for git) comes with a 'works out of the box' install.  Then you can do `cd /c/Program\ Files/StrawberryPerl/bin` (or whatever the path is).  Then `./perl.exe -MCPAN -e 'install Text::Trim'`, for example.  If that works..the module should be accessible from perl wherever you run it from.

Comment: The cpan installer is already verbose. One of the reasons cpanm was created was to avoid the verbosity. When you use cpanm, you can add verbosity using the **-v** flag. That said, I was also able to install this module using cpanm so my guess is there was some pathing in the module build script that cpanm was able to convert for windows that cpan couldn't. Just a guess though. :)

Comment: I think something's wrong in your `cpan` config. Please provide the output of `o conf` from the `cpan>` prompt.

Comment: According to this: http://www.cpan.org/modules/INSTALL.html cpanm might be the preferred install method anyway?  Strawberry perl is specifically mentioned as having it preinstalled.

Comment: Re "*might be the preferred install method anyway?*", Some people like to claim that, but there's no reason to use `cpanm` unless you're installing to a low memory (e.g. embedded) system. (At least, that's the only reason I was given for using `cpanm`, and I've asked a lot of people.) It does suppress output, but it's bad to hide warnings! Some people complain that you have to press enter to configure `cpan` the first time you run it (to have it autoconfigure), but that very small cost to pay for the extra flexibility.

Comment: @ikegami - Well, installing `cpanm` is the first actual instruction on that webpage with the note "you'll thank us later", which I'd consider pretty authoritative.  On the other hand, I'd probably consider you *more* authoritative....and I've never even used `cpanm` :)

Comment: @zzxyz, If you want authoritative, just check what comes with Perl :) That said, I don't consider either authoritative since it's a personal choice, and noone has authority over those.

Comment: @ikegami sorry for the delay, I posted the output of `o conf`. I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Sorry, don't know what you are getting that error.